# Import JSON/JSONC file in vite/typescript project

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, vue.js

want to share my routes between my actix-web backend and Vue w/ Vue-Router frontend without having to have to files describing the routes. So when I define the routes in the frontend, I don't want to change anything for the server. I don't know if there's a better solution, if so, please tell me :D

My routes.jsonc is in my src folder. Every route is of the following type:\

```
    route: { path: String; name: String; componentName: String }
```

Then my routes-Strings are converted to the actual Components:

```
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
    import ButtonArrayVue from "@/components/Home/ButtonArray.vue";
    import App from "@/App.vue";
    import * as routesImport from "../routes.jsonc";
    
    const history = createWebHistory();
    
    const routes = routesImport.map((route: { path: String; name: String; componentName: String }) => {
        let component = function () {
            switch (route.componentName) {
                case "ButtonArray":
                    return ButtonArrayVue;
                case "App":
                    return App;
            }
        };
        return {
            path: route.path,
            name: route.name,
            component: component,
        };
    });
    
    export default createRouter({
        history,
        routes,
    });
```

Now the problem is the 4th line:
I've tried multiple import statements, also:

```
import routesImport from "../routes.jsonc";
import routesImport from "src/routes.jsonc";
import routesImport from "@/routes.jsonc";
```

But I always get "Cannot find module '../routes.jsonc' or its corresponding type declarations" as a typescript and Compiler error. Sometimes also '"default" is not exported by "src/routes.jsonc", imported by "src/plugins/router.ts".'

Now to my question:
How can I import a json file without putting it in the public folder as some other questions suggest? I don't want to make this file public if possible.

Are there better alternatives? How could I import this json file?

Comment: Did you set `resolveJsonModule` to `true` inside the compiler options in the `tsconfig.json? Also you need to make sure, that vite support the `.jsonc` extension which is not the case with the default setup: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `resolveJsonModule` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`;  but note that this will ONLY work for files that are `.json` -- NOT `.jsonc`.

Comment: So polease tell me, how do I add support for `jsonc` in my project?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find an easy way.  It might be possible if you try modifying the way the Webpack builds work.

Comment: yeah probably just define '*.jsonc' in a d.ts file. Maybe a webpack loader too.